# Intel Enternet adapter l218-LM cannot reach 1Gbit speed

Tags: windows-10, gigabit-ethernet

I have a router technicolor DGA223. The router works at 1Gbit/s capacity, and other computers connecting in a wired cable to the router have 1Gbit/s  speed.

Using the same wired cable and router port to my personal computer forces the speed link to be 100Mps. Disabling energy efficiency, as well as enabling Legacy switch compatibility does not works.

I have to most updated driver version (12.18.9.10).

What can be the problem?  Is there a way to debug this problem? (i.e, an event manager\log files?)

Comment: Is there a limit inside your computer?  I am not sure. I have that NIC and a slightly different driver (Lenovo driver) and I am copying 150 GB of machines to my other computer and the speed is a very steady 112 G Bytes / second (so near the limit of the card and router).

Comment: It could be that the physical port has an issue. Driver issue is also a possibility.

Comment: @John don't think so.

Comment: @SamForbis How can I debug it?

Answer (score 0):

That adapter was first put out around 10 years ago so I would disable legacy compatibility first.  If that doesn't help try to disable duplexing if that is an available option.  Also, you could try getting the driver directly from Intel (https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22283/Intel-Ethernet-Adapter-Complete-Driver-Pack) if you are using the vendor driver.  Double check all the adapter settings if none of the above help.  Good luck.

Comment: Check all of these. It did not help :(

Comment: The driver being used here (and my own) is very new.